# General error messages for validation rules in Kohana, regardless the field name

Tags: internationalization, validation, kohana

I'm using Kohana validation library and I want to set up my own user friendly error messages. The problem is that I generate the form dynamically, so field names are not know during development.

**Can a set up error messages for the different validation rules (required, digit, ...) regardless the field name? How?**

Note: I'm using Kohana v2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I know about this problem](http://www.alexanderdickson.com/blog/2009/10/kohanas-lack-of-support-for-input-arrays/).

What I ended up doing, is something like this (though this does not know what *type* of error occurred, it worked for me in my situation).

Assume `$errors` are the errors returned from the validation library.

### My view

```
<input type="text" id="input-something" name="something" />
<?php if (isset($errors['something']): ?>
<label for="input-something" class="error">Something didn't go right!</label>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Usually I would echo the `$errors['something']` as the text node of the `label` element, but because they are defined dynamically, I just printed a general purpose error.

It's not a great solution, but you *may* be able to get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes across this using **`Kohana 3.2`**, the solution is, that you just add `validation.php` to `messages` folder and add your default values, for example:

```
return array(
    'not_empty' => "Yo dawg, this field can't be empty!",
    '[other rule]' => "[other message]",
);
```

You can look in to Kohana's source, and just copy the validation.php with default messages to your apps message folder and then just translate all of them.